REGEX: Exclude matches containing a certain string?
How can I exclude Regex matches that contain a certain string?
I have already looked up other threads concerning this topic. However, I could not find any solution so far.
The main problem is that after converting a document from DOCX to XHTML (=epub) nested lists are not correctly formattet. To demonstrate my problem, the HTML looks like:
<ol style="list-style-type: decimal">
<li>lorem1</li>
<li>lorem2</li>
<li>lorem3</li>
<li>lorem4</li>
</ol>
<ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha">
<li>ipsum-a</li>
</ol>
<ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha">
<li>ipsum-b</li>
<li>ipsum-c</li>
<li>ipsum-d</li>
</ol>
<ol style="list-style-type: decimal">
<li>lorem5</li>
</ol>
<ol style="list-style-type: decimal">
<li>lorem6</li>
</ol>

It is a numbered list that includes a lettered sub-list.
I look for a solution to match the two last OL-tags, which both belong to a closed "decimal" block. So whenever the capturing group contains a "lower-alpha" it should be excluded. Given the example above, the result should be:
<ol style="list-style-type: decimal">
<li>lorem5</li>
</ol>
<ol style="list-style-type: decimal">
<li>lorem6</li>
</ol>

My single line (//gs) REGEX so far is
(<ol[^>]+(?=decimal)[^>]+">\s*)(.*?)(<ol[^>]+(?=decimal)[^>]+">)

and gets a WRONG match, because the "lower-alpha" tag group is included. I tried something like negative look-ahead and did not get any match at all.
Since I am new to regex I cannot say if a certain regex element like a conditional match or a subfunction might be helpful.
Therefore I appreciate any help.
Regards!

Use an HTML parser (e.g. JavaScript).  Do not attempt to do this with regex.

See https://regex101.com/r/wsaPCM/1

Blocks of interest match the regular expression given here. I've written the expression in extended (aka free-spacing) mode to make it self-documenting. It therefore was necessary to protect spaces that are part of the expression, namely, the two spaces in '<ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha">' (else those spaces would be stripped out in a pre-processing step). I have done that by enclosing each in a character class. \R matches line terminators when the PCRE regex engine is used. For other engines it may be necessary to replace that with \r?\n.
